# I need to select all rows in mysql that contains more than three slashes in the uri

Tags: mysql

I need to select all rows in my mysql column that contains more than three slashes in the uri

Answer (score 1):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c027e0/2/0) demonstrating the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable  
WHERE LENGTH(url) - LENGTH(REPLACE(url, '/', '')) > 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `like`:

```
select *
from table t
where uri like '%/%/%/%';
```